# Draw forest road on Sentinel 2 TCI band

Tags: raster

By what means can I draw a non-existent forest road in the Sentinel TCI band so that it looks like a real road more or less?

I tried with GIMP but straight lines are obtained - it's not natural
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: add image to clear question